# French equivalent of "hands-on tutorial"

Tags: traduction, anglais, université

What is the equivalent of "hands-on tutorial"? Can one use *tutoriel pratique* or *formation pratique* for instance?

Comment: I expect it will depend the format (paper, digital, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tutorial, you have two main possibilities : `tutoriel` or `didacticiel`

- `Didacticiel` emphasizes on practicing but is not very common
  nowadays.
- `Formation` is generally used when it's a training with a wide scope,
  usually lasting longer and costing more than a tutorial.
- You can use the abbrieviated term `tuto` as well, if you are in a
  more familiar context.
- `Guide pratique` is also a possibility, which corresponds to "practical guide", that may suit you

`Tutoriel pratique` is a good fit overall, you can never be wrong with this :)